# How to pass a non-serializable prop from App to a saga of a child

Tags: redux-saga

I have a prop that is part of the main app. I tried to pass it as a dispatch parameter, but `reactjs/toolkit` complained that `A non-serializable value was detected in the state`.

(I think because the prop is a class instance).

How can I use this prop inside a saga?

For visualization, this is what I need to use:

[image]

I need to be able to use the the `ual` prop that is in `App`, when a user clicks a button somewhere in the `Header`.

rootStore.js (not all the code)

```
const setupStore = () => {
  const store = configureStore({
      reducer,
      middleware,
  });
  startSaga();
  return store;
};

export default setupStore;
```

rootSaga.js

```
import { all,fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import userSaga from './userSaga';

function* rootSaga() {
    console.log("hi saga")
    yield all([
        fork(userSaga),
    ]);
}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const startSaga = () => {
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  };
  
export default sagaMiddleware;
```

userSaga.js

```
export function* handleUserLogin() {
    console.log('saga handleUserLogin')
    // <=== need to use `ual` here
}

export default function* watchUserLogin() {
    yield takeEvery(fetchLoginRequest.type, handleUserLogin);
}
```

Header.js (relevant parts):

```
import { fetchLoginRequest } from '../reducers/userReducer';
const Header = (props) => {
    const {
        fetchLoginRequest,
      } = props;

    const handleLogin = () => {
        fetchLoginRequest()
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchLoginRequest,
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

The saga works, I can see the `saga handleUserLogin` is the devtools console

Comment: Is there only a single instance of the `ual` object in your App? If so, could you just pass it to the rootSaga using `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, ual);`? You can then either pass it to the nested sagas, or use `setContext/getContext` to get its value easily in any nested saga without passing it down at every level.

Comment: Yes, there is only one instance of `ual`. How to pass `ual` from `App` to `rootSaga`?

Comment: How & where do you create the `ual` instance? In the App component? In the file that renders root of your app? The entry point of your app and its imports are likely doing bunch of boot stuff to setup your app like creating your redux store & rendering root of your app, so you need to create the `ual` instance somewhere where you can then pass it both as props to your ReactDOM.render and to your rootSaga file.